# Using a plist to load content of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, xcode4, xcode4.2, plist

I have an app that uses a tableview that was created using storyboard and the titles of each cell is manually put using Storyboard, also each cell links to a different view controller that has a UIWebview.. Is there an easier way I can do this with a plist ? So basically A tableview with many cells and each cell point to a different link. (not an rss feed). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your tableView cells by creating an array of data from your plist then using something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myArrayOfData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```